# Polyglossia, Reledmac, Reledpar and a multi-alphabetical document

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, reledmac, reledpar

I am typesetting an old latin book (a Coptic grammar with Arabic examples) with a facing Italian translation. I am using the packages in the title for the management of the languages and of the alphabets (Polyglossia) and for the facing critical edition (reledmac, reledpar). Now, XeLaTeX seems to struggle with Arabic, even if, if I force the compilation, the output seems nice.

Can anyone tell me why the console returns me messages like "Failed to patch the \endminipage command" and "Package bidi Error: Oops! you have loaded package xltxtra after bidi package. Please load package xltxtra before bidi package, and then try to
run xelatex on your document again." (I did not use bidi)?.

Here my preamble with a minimum working example:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = it_IT
% !TeX root = tuki.tex    
% !BIB TS-program = biber

\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}                
    \geometry{a4paper} 

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{latin}
    \setotherlanguages{italian,arabic,greek}

\usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
\usepackage[]{fontspec} 
    \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}


\newcommand{\coptic}[1]{{\fontspec{Antinoou}{#1}}} %coptic words
\newcommand{\p}[1]{\ledouternote{p. {#1}}} %reference to the original page 




% Frontespizio
\title{Rudimenta \\ linguae \\ Coptae sive Aegyptiacae}
\author{Raphael Tuki}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{pages}

    \begin{Leftside}    
        \beginnumbering
            
            \pstart
        Lectori bevevolo. \\
        Prodit nunc ex prelis Typographiae Sacrae Congregationis de Propaganda Fide Copticae, 
sive Aegyptiacae linguae Grammatica, non eius, quae hieraticis, ac hieroglyphicis litteris exprimebatur, 
sed eius, quae post Alexandri Magni tempora, vel post Psammeticum, ut Maturino Veyfierreio La-Crozio (a) placet, 
a Graecis colonis non exiguam sortita est mutationem. 

\textarabic{الكتب المقدسة المسطرة بالنسق الواحد والاخر}

            \pend
      
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
        
    \begin{Rightside}
        
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
        Al benevolo lettore. \\ 
        Esce ora dalle battaglie della tipografia della Sacra Congregazione \emph{de Propaganda Fide} 
la grammatica della lingua copta, o egizia, non di quella che era scritta con caratteri ieratici e geroglifici, 
ma quella che dopo l'epoca di Alessandro Magno, o dopo Psammetico, come ritiene Maturin Veyssière La Croze, 
visse una non piccola trasformazione ad opera dei coloni greci.
            \pend 
        \endnumbering
        
        \end{Rightside}
    
    \end{pages}

\Pages

\end{document}
```

Comment: it's recommended not to use xltxtra or xunicode and you are using both, what are you doing that needs either of these, can't you simply remove them?

Comment: you are using bidi, look at your log or terminal output: `(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-italian.ldf)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-arabic.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidi.sty
****************************************************
* 
* bidi package (Bidirectional typesetting in
* plain TeX and LaTeX, using XeTeX engine)
`

Comment: I have removed xltxtra and xunicode packages but the error messages persists, both the \endminipage one and "Package bidi Error: Oops! you have loaded package ragged2e after bidi package. Please load package ragged2e before bidi package, and then try to run xelatex on your document again."

Comment: polyglossia is loading bidi and reledmac is loading ragged2e so the error is asking you load polyglossia later

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand those messages! I've switched the position of the two packages and everything is working fine!

Answer (score 1):

`polyglossia` is loading `bidi` and `reledmac` is loading `ragged2e` so the error is asking you load `polyglossia` later in the preamble.